# Redirect URL with query string on same domain but different directory using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am trying to redirect a page to another page along with query string. 
Example:

The URL below

```
http://example.com/firstdir/?abc=xyz
```

needs to redirect to the below URL with same query string on same domain.

```
http://example.com/seconddir/?abc=xyz
```

When there are no query string added in the URL, it should stay on the same page and will not redirect.

I have tried to explain what I am looking for, please HELP !!!

tHANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your .htaccess in your root folder and it will handle recursive folders.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the .htaccess file is already at root folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^firstdir/?$ /seconddir [NC,L,R=302]
```

Query string is automatically carried over to target URL

Comment: Thanks anubhava, I have tried the given code but couldn't succeed. May be because I am using WordPress and it conflicts with WP default rewrite rules.

I have used plug-in Safe Redirect Manager and it fixed the issue.

Thanks for the help...

Comment: If it is Wordpress then place above rule rule as very first rule, just below `RewtiteEngine` line in WP .htaccess